# How can we encode the Multi JSON data response in ajax

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have a problem with json encoded information which loaded via ajax.I pass the multi JSON to the ajax for display the field value.

How can i fetch the field value from the json using query ajax.

ajax code :

```
                   ....success:function(data){
                    var TotalBuyPrice = 0;
                    var TotalItem = 0;
                    $.each(data, function(c,cart){

                        //Condition follow  1
                      var InStockQty =cart.products_qty;
                      alert(InStockQty);

                         //And also follow  2
                       var name =cart["withoutdiscount"][0]["products_name"];
                        alert(name); 

                    });
                     }...
```

The PHP code :

These are my steps following for json response.By using array collect the result

```
        $response = array();
        $response['withoutdiscount'] = $withoutdiscount;
        $response['withdiscount'] = $withdiscount;

        echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($response). ');';
```

jsoncallback:

```
         ({"withoutdiscount":[{"products_id":"1","products_name":"Lumia"}],
            "withdiscount":[{"products_id":"2","discount_qty":"8"},
                            {"products_id":"3","discount_qty":"1"}
                           ]
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve the problem like this:
Using PHP file get one response like this:

```
    $response = array();
    $response['withoutdiscount'] = $withoutdiscount;
    $response['withdiscount'] = $withdiscount;

    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($response). ');';
```

jsoncallback: //JSON response

```
     ({"withoutdiscount":[{"products_id":"1","products_name":"Lumia"}],
        "withdiscount":[{"products_id":"2","discount_qty":"8"},
                        {"products_id":"3","discount_qty":"1"}
                       ]
      });
```

using ajax  function  call the json response like this:

```
        function querySuccess(tx,results) {
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(results);
            $.ajax({
                url:'getcart.php',
                data: {data : jsonString},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                timeout: 5000,
                success:function(data){
                    var withdiscount=data.withdiscount;
                    var withoutdiscount=data.withoutdiscount;
                if(withdiscount!='')
                {
                    $.each(withdiscount, function(c,cart){
                       var discount_qty =cart.discount_qty;
                        alert(discount_qty);
                     );
                 }
                if(withoutdiscount!='')
                {
                    $.each(withoutdiscount, function(c,cart){ 
                       var products_name =cart.products_name;
                          alert(products_name);
                     });
                }
               }
            });
        }
```

This is working with me.

NOTE: There is only 2 JSON response is pass so i given directly.